# io.Copy is not copying data between os.File types

Tags: go

I am creating 2 files from code using os.Create function.

I am writing some string to file1 and then trying to copy the content of file1 to file2 using io.Copy but its not working.

There are no errors thrown. Can anyone tell me what is happening here ? Thanks.

Playground Link - https://play.golang.org/p/lv_2VfsNIfI

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {

    file1, err := os.Create("file1")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    file1.WriteString("Some test data")
    defer file1.Close()
    defer os.Remove(file1.Name())

    log.Println("File1 Data : ", readFile(file1.Name()))

    file2, err := os.Create("file2")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer file2.Close()
    defer os.Remove(file2.Name())

    w, err := io.Copy(file2, file1)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    log.Println("Copied", w)

    log.Println("File2 Data : ", readFile(file2.Name()))
}

func readFile(fname string) string {
    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile(fname)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    return string(data)
}
```

Output I am getting,

```
2009/11/10 23:00:00 File1 Data :  Some test data
2009/11/10 23:00:00 Copied 0
2009/11/10 23:00:00 File2 Data :
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to seek back to the beginning of file1 using `file1.Seek(0,io.SeekStart)` because your file cursor is at the end of the written data.

Seek function receives two parameters:

**offset** of type int64: This represents the number of bytes to move the file pointer.

**whence** of type int: This is used to determine the reference point for the offset. It can take one of the three values: io.SeekStart, io.SeekCurrent, or io.SeekEnd. These values indicate whether the offset should be counted from the beginning, the current position, or the end of the file, respectively.

```
...
file1.WriteString("Some test data")
file.Seek(0,io.SeekStart)
defer file1.Close()
...
```

Go Standard Library Documentation Links

[io.Seek](https://pkg.go.dev/os#File.Seek)
[io.StartSeek](https://pkg.go.dev/io#SeekStart)

Comment: Thanks Man, its working now.

Comment: @akshaykhairmode May you could accept my answer then? Thanks

Comment: I was trying to do so, but there seems to be some timer which was not allowing me to accept it. Have done it now :)

Comment: No prob, thanks :)